# Get Proximity Information of Estimote Beacons without official API?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, ibeacon, estimote

I want to develop an platform independent framework providing proximity information by using Estimote Beacons and Java. Is this even possible? I tried out some of those official Android Tutorials using the EstimoteSDK and they work fine. Could I also use for instance the Google Beacons API(https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/guides) or an other libary to get the Proximity Information out of the Estimote Beacons?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I work as a Developer Advocate at Estimote*

You might want to take a look at hybrid frameworks like PhoneGap or Xamarin.

Evothings maintains a PhoneGap plugin for Estimote Beacons that provides a single JavaScript API to range and monitor beacons on iOS and Android:

https://github.com/evothings/phonegap-estimotebeacons

Xamarin has two separate components for iOS and Android, so it's a bit less convenient, as *I think* (hopefully somebody more familiar with Xamarin platform can confirm/deny in a comment) that means two separate APIs:

https://components.xamarin.com/view/estimotesdkandroid
https://components.xamarin.com/view/estimotesdkios

You should be able to use these to range and monitor for Estimotes, but also beacons from other vendors.

For a truly vendor-agnostic option, you can try this one:

https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon

Answer (score 0):

**One alternative is the open source [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/)**, which is free under the Apache 2 license and supports a wide variety of beacons formats.  The Google Beacons API is better suited for integrating with Google services (if that is your goal), especially when using Eddystone beacons.

Other than being free and open source, the other advantages of the Android Beacon Library are that it is widely used (1.5 million installs on over 4,000 apps) so it is easy to get community support.  And it is configurable to support a wide variety of beacon formats including Eddystone and AltBeacon.

Full Disclosure:  I am the lead developer on the Android Beacon Library open source project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thing is I was looking for something platform independant...i mean in theory java should run on windows, android and iOs right? I know propably it's not that easy but there is for example https://robovm.com/ which allows writing java code for iOs. My goal is to write a java framework which I can include as a dependency for lets say android AND iOs devices. I assume that the android Beacon libary is only working for Android...is it?

Comment: The main issue is not the programming language but the underlying Bluetooth LE API.  Each platform has a different API for accessing it.  While it might be possible to make a multi-platform framework in a single language, you'd still be limited by the language bindings available for the platform.  You can't run Java on iOS.  You can't run Objective C on Android.  You'd have more luck with a multi-platform framework on non-mobile platforms like Windows, OSX and Linux which don't restrict the languages that run on the platform.

Comment: Ah okay they use a different bluetooth API...did'nt know not. Thanks for clarification